# Paypal Sync Api last_refreshed_datetime - what does it mean, how often it refreshes?

Tags: paypal

Paypal documentation for PayPal Sync API (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/sync/v1/).

It gives some mysterious date, named "last_refreshed_datetime".

On the sandbox server it is usually in the past, once it was a few days in the past, now it is 2 hours in the past.

What does it mean? How often it refreshes?

I only know that if I create a transaction it will not be visible on PayPal Sync API until the refresh date will not be later than the transaction date. And I'm guessing it should be the `transaction approval date` that does not presented on this report. The transaction approval date is available on transaction object (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#definition-transaction), it is called "time".

> `time` string
>
> The date and time when the transaction was processed, in Internet date and time format.
> Read only.

Answer (score 3):

I have reached out to the product development team for the SYNC API and have gotten the following clarifications in regards to your questions:

> If the "last_refreshed_datetime" (Time until which we have data available in our system) is smaller than the requested end date then,  in the API response we show end date as "last_refreshed_datetime". As we only have data up until that point. In general there should be around **4-6hrs** of delay.

From my own experience on sandbox, on different occasions it was 6.5, 2.5 hours and even 2 days behind.